# SVN Log :: how to extract svn logs by grepping a particular pattern present in comment

Tags: svn, unix

when ever developer checks in the code in svn, he/she enters the ticket# for which the fix is delivered, in the comments field. Now I want to extract the svn logs for this ticket# only. Can anyone please advice me how can I modify the svn log command so that I can get a list of all files which were checked in using that ticket#

PFB dummy example:

```
svn log <svn url>
o/p::

r1000 | author | 2013-04-19 11:48:16

    A abc.txt``
    M def.txtD ``
      pqr.txt``

    ticket#::filescheckedin
```

Now if I grep `ticket#`, i do not get list of the files which were modified uner it.
Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this kind of thing I like the more structured (but possible resource heavier) approach of using `svn log -v --xml` & examine it with xml/xpath libs.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Scenario is that when I, say for eg. check in 10 files in a single commit with a single comment. later on by grepping a particular pattern in comment field (say for eg ticket#) I need to extract the list of all files which were checked in with that comment. Hope this helps. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could write a small perl (or whatever you like, using the libsvn interface) program which uses libsvn-perl. There you can retrieve the log via the given interface. It will give you details about each single commit in one function call. There you can grep the commit message and print the needed information, if you have found your ticket ID or just ignore this commit and print nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with GNU awk:

```
svn log ... | gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "----*\n" }
/ticketnumber/ { print $0 }'
```

where ticketnumber is the string you want to search for.

This works by setting the input record separator to the line of dashes that svn prints between log records, and just matching the records you want.

Note that you need gawk, not awk, for this to work.